# String Regex for insert text based on searchstring

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

I have the following class.

```
  public class TestStringRegex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("KALAKA");
        String wordToFind = "KA";
        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

        while (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.end());
            text=text.insert(match.end(),"INSERT");

        }
        System.out.println(text);


    }
```

Expecting output to be KAINSERTLAKAINSERT.
But getting KAINSERTLAKA.
Is matcher/insert works on the length of input text?How to get desired output.

Comment: Try `"KALAKA".replaceAll("KA", "$0INSERT")`

Comment: I would avoid using a matcher repeatedly on a `StringBuilder` while modifying the `StringBuilder` at the same time.  Unless you have javadoc that says that this will work, or that explains exactly what the behavior is, I don't think you can count on its behavior being predictable at all.  If you have a complex situation where you can't use `replaceAll`, my choice would be to create a list in which you collect the planned edits, and then go through this list after all the matches have been found.

Comment: As things stand, I cannot figure out why your code doesn't work and Mritunjay's answer works.  I don't see any javadoc that says anything about the behavior.  I may have to dig through the `Matcher` code to figure out.

Comment: do we need to set the region as well in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it using `matcher` use the overloaded method with `int` i.e. `matcher.find(index)`. For some reason `mathcher.find()` is not working as given in docs. If you are curious you need to debug the code.

Just say like below

```
int end = 0;
while (match.find(end)) {
    end = match.end();
    System.out.println(end);
    text=text.insert(end,"INSERT");
}
```

#### Better way of doing the same will be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("KALAKA".replaceAll("KA", "$0INSERT"));
}
```

That's all the code you need to write.

Comment: Can you explain why this works and using `find()` doesn't?  If you look at the javadoc for [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) and [`end`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end--), it appears that the two should behave equivalently.  Given that, I think the behavior may well be a bug, and in any case is unpredictable and should not be counted on.  It looks like a bad idea to use repeated matches on a `StringBuilder` while it's being modified.

Comment: @ajb, I was updating my answer, I was debugging the same piece of code. The problem I feel when we are modifying the `StringBuilder` in this line `text=text.insert(end,"INSERT");`. As soon as we modify the builder the `matcher.find()` return `false`. If you don't modify the builder and call it twice it works fine.

Comment: Right, I'd expect it to work fine if you don't modify it in between.  By the way, I figured out that the reason for the difference is that `find(end)` _resets the matcher_, according to the javadoc, and that includes reinitializing some internal variables including variables that hold the start and end of the search region.  I still don't have an answer as to why the OP's code doesn't work.  Looking at the `Matcher` code, it seems like it should work even without the reset.

Answer (score 0):

Use matcher.find(int startIndex) instead of find(). And update startIndex after each match. Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("KALAKA");
        String wordToFind = "KA";
        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

        int findIndex = 0;
        while (match.find(findIndex)) {
            int end = match.end();
            findIndex = end;
            text = text.insert(end, "INSERT");

        }
        System.out.println(text);

    }
```

Each next find() starts at the end of previous match

Comment: See my comment on Mritunjay's answer.  I would not recommend this solution.

Comment: On top of that, try your code changing `"INSERT"` to `"HACKATHON"`.  Watch what happens!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine..!!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("KALAKA");
    String wordToFind = "KA";
    Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
    Matcher match = word.matcher(text);
    int end = 0;
    while (match.find(end)) {
        end = match.end();
        text=text.insert(match.end(),"INSERT");
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: You've posted code that is equivalent to two earlier answers.  Why?